# webbrowserで自動操作によるボタン押下後の画面推移について

Tags: c#

あるページのボタンを押下すると画面が推移するのですが、
webbrowserを自動操作した場合、メソッド(form上のボタンクリックによるイベント)を抜けないと画面が移動しません。

ページのボタン押下後にrefreshやupdateを試してはみましたが上手く行きませんでした。
１度メソッドを抜けないとwebbrowserの画面推移は難しいでしょうか？

visual studio express 2015

Answer (score 0):

> メソッド(form上のボタンクリックによるイベント)を抜けないと画面が移動しません。

質問の意図は分かりかねますが、一般論としてWindows Formsの描画やUI処理はシングルスレッドで動作しています。OSや他のコンポーネントによる処理を行うためにも、イベント処理などは速やかに完了させ、OSに制御を戻す必要があります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
>質問の意図は分かりかねますが、
⇒メソッド(form上のボタンクリックによるイベント)を抜けないと画面が移動しない
となると、目的の自動処理を行うにはボタンを複数用意して毎回順番にボタンを手動で押して少しづつWEBページの自動操作する形になってしまいます。
それは理想の形からかなり離れてしまうのでなんとか方法はないかと質問させていただいた次第です。

Comment: @MAHOTO さん、本質問は「移動するかどうか、移動させるにはどうする必要があるか」ですが、そもそも移動すれば解決するものではなく、ブラウザーの読み込み完了を待つ必要があります。ですので「移動させる」という質問はあまり意味を成しません。

Answer (score 0):

UIの操作をすぐに戻したいのであれば、ボタンの中のメソッドを非同期にしてみては？

Answer (score 0):

ボタン押下時にタイマーを起動して、ボタン押下処理を抜け、タイマーイベントで逐次webbrowserの自動操作をしたらどうでしょうか？